# Как в Pandas сделать уникальный список из 2-х и более файлов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

У меня есть несколько файлов, в которых пересекаются некоторые строки. Мне нужно сделать один список только с уникальными значениями.

**file1** содержит:

```
собака
кошка
барсук
заяц
лиса
волк
```

**file2** содержит:

```
медведь
соболь
сова
заяц
белка
кошка
енот
```

Мне нужно, получить в результате один список включающий все значения из первого файла, и только те строки из второго, которых не достает в первом:

Итоговый файл должен быть таким:

```
собака, file1
кошка, file1
барсук, file1
заяц, file1
лиса, file1
волк, file1
медведь, file2
соболь, file2
сова, file2
белка, file2
```

Из второго списка вылетели три строки, поскольку они уже есть:

> ```
> заяц
> кошка
> енот
> ```

Comment: С чем возникла проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Более универсальный вариант решения - может обрабатывать больше двух файлов:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

data_dir = Path(r'D:\temp\data')

df = (pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, header=None, names=['name'])
                   .assign(file=f.stem)
                   .set_index('name')
                for f in data_dir.glob('*.txt')])
        .reset_index()
        .drop_duplicates(subset=['name']))

df.to_csv(r'd:/temp/res.txt', header=None, index=False)
```

Результат:

```
собака,file1
кошка,file1
барсук,file1
заяц,file1
лиса,file1
волк,file1
медведь,file2
соболь,file2
сова,file2
белка,file2
енот,file2
единорог,file3
бармаглот,file3
```

---

Примеры входных файлов:

file1.txt:

```
собака
кошка
барсук
заяц
лиса
волк
```

file2.txt:

```
медведь
соболь
сова
заяц
белка
кошка
енот
```

file3.txt:

```
заяц
единорог
кошка
бармаглот
енот
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = pd.read_csv(r'D:\temp\file1.txt', header=None, names=['name']).assign(file='file1')
d2 = pd.read_csv(r'D:\temp\file2.txt', header=None, names=['name']).assign(file='file2')

res = d1.append(d2[~d2['name'].isin(d1['name'])])

res.to_csv(r'd:/temp/res.txt', header=None, index=False)
```

Результат:

```
In [76]: print(Path(r'd:/temp/res.txt').read_text(encoding='utf-8'))
собака,file1
кошка,file1
барсук,file1
заяц,file1
лиса,file1
волк,file1
медведь,file2
соболь,file2
сова,file2
белка,file2
енот,file2
```